# Removing google ads dependency and forget to remove meta-data from manefest file

Tags: android, google-play, ads

Yesterday, I posted my first app on Google Play. It is still waiting for review. At first I was planning to add ads to the app for this I used firebase assistant in Android studio. So it add:

build.gradle [app]

```
...
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
...

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'
}
```

build.gradle[Project]

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
```

and in manefest file:

```
<manifest ...>
    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application ...>

        <!--
        This is the sample AdMob App ID. Insert your own AdMob App ID in quotes
        https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

            ....
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In the end, I decided to remove the ads from the app so I remove this line from gradle file and all the usage from the code:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'
```

I forgot to delete the others lines:

this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this line:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
```

and this (permession and meta-data)

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application ...>

    <!--
    This is the sample AdMob App ID. Insert your own AdMob App ID in quotes
    https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

        ....
</application>
```

In google play console, when ask:
Does your app contains ads? I choose No.

My question is because of this error, will my application be rejected or not?
Is there a way to fix this error before Google reviews it?

Comment: Send a new release with your changes :)

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi thanks for your reply, even if the app is not accepted yet, i can update it?

Comment: yes you can update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, your application will not be rejected. If you want, you can publish a new update now and Google Play will check this one new update instead of previous with this issue.